# DatePicker and Calendar Display format Year+543 for thai year (buddhist year)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iview-ui

How display format for Thai year because Thai-year uses Buddhist-Era (B.E.) that is 543 years greater than Christian-Era (C.E.).
Example.
2019-01-31 format for Thai year 2562-01-31

Thanks you.

Comment: Possibly relevant: [display format for year buddhist (Thai year) #285](https://github.com/mengxiong10/vue2-datepicker/issues/285)